# Emacs 24 Eww(Browser) - buffer and project open and refresh

Tags: emacs, emacs24, eww

In Emacs 24 there is a new feature Eww which is the Emacs web browser.

I am using this resource [ergoemacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_eww_web_browser.html) as a reference.

Looking through describe mode I can see a list of commands but not for what I want to do.

Describe mode

```
CTRL+h m
```

I want to be able to link an index.html file as the root file of a project and open the file in Eww and refresh automatically when I make updates.

There is also the other option of

```
eww-browse-with-external-browser
```

So I can create a split window

```
split-window-right
```

But how can I tie it together in 2 key combos to open current file in eww-internal and eww-external and refresh automatically on updates in project?

Just key binding isn't working for me.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x a") 'eww-browse-with-external-browser)
```

NB if it helps I am using Helm, unsure if this would help but it current seems awesome and I am only scratching the surface of what it can do.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It should be either in superuser.com or the beta emacs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Barmar         are all the emacs questions on stackoverflow going to be moved?

Comment: No idea. Probably not. Some are probably about programming in Emacs Lisp, that's on-topic here.

Comment: @Barmar         yeah too much of a fine line to call just end up with emacs questions sprayed over all the sites and that’s probably not desirable.